# Make Dictionary with only keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, append, key

I need to make a dictionary containing only keys.

I cannot use `d.append()` as it is not a list, neither `setdefault` as it needs 2 arguments: a key and a value.

It should work as the following:

```
d = {}
```

add "a":

```
d = {"a"}
```

add "b":

```
d = {"a", "b"}
```

add "c"...

```
# Final result is:

d = {"a", "b", "c"}
```

What is the code I need to get this result?
Or is it another solution? Such as making a list.

```
l = ["a", "b", "c"] # and transform it into a dictionary: d = {"a", "b", "c"} ?
```

Comment: `d = {"a", "b", "c"}` It's not a dictionary It's a `set` only

Comment: If you started with `d = set()` instead of `d = {}`, it would have worked.

Comment: you need a `set` not a dictionary

Comment: `dict.fromkeys('abc')` will give you `{'a': None, 'c': None, 'b': None}`, however it sounds like what you want is a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Answer (score 25):

A `dict` with only keys is called a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Start with an empty set instead of a dictionary.

```
d = set()
d.add('a')
d.add('b')
d.add('c')
```

You can also create a set via a `{}` expression:

```
d = { 'a', 'b', 'c' }
```

Or using a list:

```
d = set(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: and how I retrive value b? in a dictionary I don't need to iterate over it

Comment: @LeonardoRick You can get the elements of a set by iterating it. In a dict if you already have a key you can look up the associated value, but in a set there is no value. So if you already have the key, there is nothing to look up. Or what are you asking?

Comment: I already have the key, but  wan't to check if this key is in the set. In a dict It will be fast as `if 'key' in dict`. Can I do that on a set? What's de difference of doing this on a set, dict or even a list

Comment: @LeonardoRick Yes `if key in myset` is as fast as `if key in mydict`. Much faster than in a list. See [docs for set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Comment: Important note: `set` will not preserve the insertion order. `print(d)` will print `{'b', 'c', 'a'}` (not {'a', 'b', 'c',})

Answer (score 9):

That should do it:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c"]

d = {k:None for k in l}
```

As @Rahul says in the comments, `d = {"a", "b", "c"}` is not a valid dictionary definition since it is lacking the values. You need to have values assigned to keys for a dictionary to exist and if you are lacking the values you can just assign `None` and update it later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not what I want. This returns
{'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None} And I don't want the "None"

Comment: @MartinM You have to have something. It does not have to be `None`. It might as well be an empty string (`''`).

Comment: Rahul K P and khelwood found the solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thats awesome - thanks :)

Comment: @MartinM and the solution is ...?

Comment: @user8395964 you can see it in their answers; use a `set`

Answer (score 6):

You need a `set` not a dictionary,

```
l = ["a", "b", "c"]
d = set(l)
```